# Calling roscore from subprocess

Tags: ros, python, pyqt, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a GUI written in python 2.7 using PyQt4 that launches various husky_navigation demos via python's subprocess command. Here is an example:

```
cmd = "%s; %s;" % (self.exportMaster, self.exportHostName)
        self.huskyNavRoscore = subprocess.Popen(cmd + ROS_BIN + "roscore", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        time.sleep(2)

        # launches gazebo
        self.huskyNavGazebo = subprocess.Popen(cmd + "roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_playpen.launch", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        time.sleep(2)

        #launches Rviz
        self.huskyNavRviz = subprocess.Popen(cmd + "roslaunch husky_viz view_robot.launch", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        time.sleep(2)

        # enables navigation
        self.huskyNavMoveBase = subprocess.Popen(cmd + "roslaunch husky_navigation move_base_mapless_demo.launch", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

When executing these lines in my deployed executable, the console gets flooded with errors saying:

```
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/rosout/rosout: error while loading shared libraries: libroscpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
failed to start local process: /opt/ros/indigo/lib/rosout/rosout __name:=rosout __log:=/home/hatfield/.ros/log/f2ee00dc-5914-11e6-a8c3-4c3488a90e5c/rosout-1.log
failed to start local process: /opt/ros/indigo/lib/rosout/rosout __name:=rosout __log:=/home/hatfield/.ros/log/f2ee00dc-5914-11e6-a8c3-4c3488a90e5c/rosout-1.log
[rosout-1] process has died [pid 14653, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/rosout/rosout __name:=rosout __log:=/home/hatfield/.ros/log/f2ee00dc-5914-11e6-a8c3-4c3488a90e5c/rosout-1.log].
log file: /home/hatfield/.ros/log/f2ee00dc-5914-11e6-a8c3-4c3488a90e5c/rosout-1*.log
```

However, when I run the raw GUI using "python GUI.py" these commands run and start the husky_navigation demo just fine. I believe this may be a problem with launching roscore within an executable file. Am I totally off?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240969/calling-roscore-from-subprocess/) by [dicegame](https://answers.ros.org/users/27504/dicegame/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like an environment issue: do you start your *deployed* UI / program from a shell that has sourced the appropriate `setup.*` files?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dicegame](https://answers.ros.org/users/27504/dicegame/) on 2016-08-05**:
AH! I feel so dumb. I was sourcing ROS's setup.bash in my ~/.bashrc and not in my subprocess calls. I'm no longer getting the error. Thanks!

**Comment by [dicegame](https://answers.ros.org/users/27504/dicegame/) on 2016-08-05**:
Subprocess calls weren't sourcing ROS's setup.bash in my subprocess calls.

**Comment by [kinglm](https://answers.ros.org/users/37878/kinglm/) on 2018-10-02**:
Hi, I'm running into a similar problem, but I don't understand the solution : how do I source ROS's setup.bash in the subprocess call? Could you just put up the modified code where the problem is solved? Thanks!